# Open sets containing closed set which contain open sets

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

This is perhaps a more general question, but is there any name for a topological space which supports the following structure? Given any open set $A$ in the topology and some point $x$, there exists a closed set $B$ and another open set $A'$ which satisfy

$$
x \in A' \subset B \subset A
$$
?

That such a structure is supported is clear in, e.g., metric spaces (with the usual topology generated by the distance function) by letting $S$ be the open ball which contains $x$ and picking $B$ to be the closed ball centered at $x$ with half of the distance of $x$ to the boundary of $A$. Then $A'$ can simply be, say, the interior of $B$.

Perhaps there may not be a name for *this particular case*, but is there a name for an equivalent (or slightly stronger) property of a space?

Comment: That is the exact definition of a [*regular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space) topological space.

Comment: Ah, I see; the construction I was thinking about actually requires compactness (! which I didn't state in the question, so it is besides the point), but yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An Example:**

Locally compact Hausdorff space $X$: For every $x\in X$ and any open set $G$ that containing $x$, there is a compact set $K$ and an open set $H$ such that $x\in H\subseteq K\subseteq G$.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: "Locally compact Hausdorff" ***implies*** "regular" but is far from being equivalent.

Comment: So I have given a stronger topological space which has the given property.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris, regular topology is the one you need, not locally compact Hausdorff space.