# For given open set $O$ under what conditions we can find a closed (or compact) set $C$ and open set $U$ s.t. $U\subseteq C\subseteq O$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Under what conditions we can find such sets as given in the title? For example, if $X$ is a metric space this is obvious. Or, we can devise some topology that this holds but I'm not looking for something like that. Is normality of $X$ enough? regularity? Haussdorf + locally compact enough?

Comment: This is probably not what you actually want to ask about. As stated at the moment, $U=C=\emptyset$ trivially works.

Comment: @Thorgott Yes :). Unfortunately. They should me non-empty.

Comment: I found the answer: [Open set containing closed set containing open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744141/open-sets-containing-closed-set-which-contain-open-sets). But it doesn't give the proof. I would really like to see why it is true for locally compact Haussdorf spaces.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is regular, and the latter condition is equivalent to: for every $x \in X$, for every open neighbourhood $U_x$, there exists an open neighbourhood $V_x$ such that $x \in V_x \subset \overline V_{x} \subset U$. If you want your $C$ to be compact, and not only closed, this will also work, since you are in a locally compact Hausdorff space and you can find plenty of precompact open sets.

Comment: @arnett You can put this comment as an answer if you want. And, if you don't mind, Can you show regularity implies what you just wrote. I couldn't quite see why that should be the case.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç That's an alternative definition on regularity. Equivalence is shown on every book in general topology. Just apply the regularity definition w.r.t. the point $x$ and the closed set $X-U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets write an answer using the comments provided by @arnett.

Let $O$ be a non-empty open set. Consider the point $x\in O$ and closed set $X/O$. By regularity, $T_3$, of $X$ we can find disjoint open sets $U,W$ s.t. $x\in U$ and $X/O\subseteq W$. This shows $U\subseteq O$. Otherwise $U$ would contain an element from the set $X/O$ which contradicts the fact $U\cap W=\emptyset$. Similarly, $\overline{U}\subseteq O$ as well. Because if $\overline{U}\nsubseteq O$ Then, $\partial U$ contains an element $y$ from the open set $W$. But this would mean $v\notin \partial U$. Therefore, we have $\overline{U}\subseteq O$ as well.

To summarize, We find that, in a regular space X, for any non-empty open set $O$, there exists open set $U$ and closed set $C$ s.t.
$$ U\subseteq C \subseteq O$$ where $C$ was $\overline{U}$ in our proof.

If we have a locally compact space, it is easy to make $C$ a compact set.